# Is there List type that can be Enumerated while it is Changing?

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, asp.net-4.5

Sometimes it is useful to enumerate a list while it is changing.

e.g.

```
foreach (var item in listOfEntities)
  item.Update();

// somewhere else (with someEntity contained in listOfEntities)
// an add or remove is made:
someEntity.OnUpdate += (s,e) => listOfEntities.Remove(someEntity);
```

This will fail if `listOfEntities` is a `List<T>`.

There are workarounds like making a copy or a simple for-loop, each with different drawbacks, but I would like to know if there is a list type in the framework (or open source) that supports this.

Comment: It isn't a limitation of `List<T>`. It is an enumerator limitation, so no... use `for` instead of `foreach`.

Comment: @M.Babcock: Sure, you *can* use a `for` loop, but that doesn't mean your program is going to behave properly.

Comment: @EdS. - Even if there was such an implementation (Jon Skeet's queue to chime in to prove me wrong) there is no guarantee that the OP's program is going to behave correctly.

Comment: @M.Babcock: Well, yeah.... that's kind of my point :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at the collections in System.Collections.Concurrent.  There's no list there, but the collections' enumerators do "represents a moment-in-time snapshot of the contents of the [collection]".

These collections are designed for access from multiple threads, so they will be better suited to applications like the code sample you posted.

Comment: +1 I don't write a lot of multi-threaded C# code, I always forget about those.

Comment: +1. Note that if it single threaded case I'd prefer to explicitly copy collection before iteration if modifications are expected - it will make very clear that iteration is happening over items that may or may not be in the collection anymore.

Answer (score 4):

This has nothing to do with `List<T>`; it is a limitation of the enumerator.  If you change the state of the collection underneath the enumerator it will throw, period.

You *could* use a `for` loop, but you will then run into logical errors as you index into a collection after the number of items have changed.

It's probably a bad idea to swap items in and out of a collection while you are enumerating it in another thread.  I would stick with the tried and true method of recording the items to be removed in another collection or locking the collection while it is being enumerated.

I'm not claiming this is an impossible problem to solve, I just don't know of an easy way to do it.